# Pelican -- 'articles_page' is undefined

Tags: python, pelican, static-generator

I've created my own theme for Pelican and I've been using it for a while to build my site. I've decided to start blogging again so I'm only now adding the blog features to the site.

I've created my own `blog.html` template to render the content in the way I want. I started by copying and pasting the code from the *'simple' theme* that comes with Pelican to get me started, but even though it is unchanged I'm getting an `'articles_page' is undefined` error when I try to build.

Where is the `article_page` variable set from? I tried adding to my `pelicanconf.py` file but it didn't help.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ page.title }} — Ricky White{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}  

<section class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <ol id="post-list">
                {% for article in articles_page.object_list %}
                    <li><article class="hentry">
                            <header> <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to {{ article.title|striptags }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h2> </header>
                            <footer class="post-info">
                                <time class="published" datetime="{{ article.date.isoformat() }}"> {{ article.locale_date }} </time>
                                <address class="vcard author">By
                                {% for author in article.authors %}
                                    <a class="url fn" href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ author.url }}">{{ author }}</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </address>
                            </footer><!-- /.post-info -->
                            <div class="entry-content"> {{ article.summary }} </div><!-- /.entry-content -->
                    </article></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ol><!-- /#posts-list -->
            {% if articles_page.has_other_pages() %}
                {% include 'pagination.html' %}
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Can you also paste your flask's route here?

Comment: I'm using Pelican, the static site generator, not Flask.

Answer (score 1):

You must have referenced your template from one of the articles using:

```
Template: blog
```

If you remove that reference and add the following lines to your *pelicanconf.py*, Pelican will generate blog.html directly from your template file:

```
DIRECT_TEMPLATES = ['index', 'blog']
PAGINATED_DIRECT_TEMPLATES = ['blog']
```

(Do not forget to empty your output folder before running pelican. Tested on Pelican 3.7.1)

Comment: I did what you suggested, but it still gives me articles_page is undefined

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of future visitors who might come here looking for an answer like I did:

The problem can have a good number of very diverse reasons.  In my case it was not a problem with the configuration of the pelican tooling, but rather an error in the metadata of some of my content pages.  I had not included the correct category, date or tag fields.  You'd never guess that from the error message now, would you?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question looking for the same error.

In my case the reason was an [issue](https://github.com/arulrajnet/attila/issues/29) which has been closed but not merged in the [current release](https://github.com/arulrajnet/attila/releases/tag/v1.3) of the [Attila](https://github.com/arulrajnet/attila) theme. More precisely: the error is caused by a template in the `templates` folder of the theme which has a wrong reference inside it. In the specific case, inside the `page` template there was a wrong reference to `article`.

Changing the template manually fixed the issue:

```sh
--- a/attila-1.3/templates/page.html
+++ b/attila-1.3/templates/page.html
@@ -21,8 +21,8 @@
   {% else %}
     {% set selected_cover = SITEURL+"/"+HEADER_COVER %}
   {% endif %}
-{% elif article.color %}
-  {% set selected_color = article.color %}
+{% elif page.color %}
+  {% set selected_color = page.color %}
 {% elif HEADER_COLOR %}
   {% set selected_color = HEADER_COLOR %}
 {% endif %}
```

I hope this helps debugging similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

The page variable `articles_page` is set in only one place: `Writer._get_localcontext` and there is a guard condition:

```py
if paginated and template_name in self.settings['PAGINATED_TEMPLATES']:
   # ... code ...
   paginated_kwargs.update(
                        {'%s_paginator' % key: paginator,
                         '%s_page' % key: page,                    # <-- Creates `article_page`
                         '%s_previous_page' % key: previous_page,
                         '%s_next_page' % key: next_page})
```

If this problem crops up, the easiest solution is to make sure the guard condition evaluates to `True`. Most likely, the problem is that `template_name` is not in `PAGINATED_TEMPLATES` in your configuration file. I opened **writers.py**, added a `print(f"template_name is {template_name}")` and got my answer (I didn't have `author : None` in my `PAGINATED_TEMPLATES` dictionary).